# Multibit images/screenshots in educational website

Tags: multibit

I would like to confirm/verify if I could use some images/screenshots of multibit on my educational website for my wallet section.

Also, if you had a high resolution image of your multibit gray bitcoin logo that is greater than 175x175 pixels that would be fantastic!

Thanks!
Derek

Comment: Just realised this isn't a multibit forum. Does anyone know how I can get into contact with someone from the multibit team?

Answer (score 2):

I'm one of the MultiBit devs.

Everything with MultBit is MIT licence so you are free to reuse anything. The website is also open source and is on github as the project multibit-website.

There are some larger icons in the github for multibit - it's in something like src/main/resources/images. I think there is a 512x512 pixel one in there